# Liquibase: How to create update changelog after modifing database directly?

Tags: liquibase

We are trying to apply liquibase to our project. With current state, my database has been recorded by liquibase, but what happen if one developer edit the database directly not using liquibase (edit tables that created by liquibase)? Because sometime he wants to use other tools for change the database quickly (such as PLSQL, SQL Developer,...), how we can create update changelog file (only include new changeset) in this case ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Use liquibase [diff](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html) - or ask more specifically

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48193745/332248) might also help.

Comment: Thanks Jens, when I use this command diff it show unmanaged objecst, because I change db directly